# GeoDjango: Can't save a model with PointField(), Error: SpatialProxy (POINT) with value of type: <class 'users.models.Point'>

Tags: django, geodjango

The idea is to integrate Google Maps instead of the default map for GeoDjango v1.11.5 `PointField()`.

Currently, in my **models.py**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='Teacher')
    placename = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Latitude')
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Longitude')
    location = models.PointField(blank = True, null=True, srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location = Point(self.longitude, self.latitude)
        super(Teacher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.
```

However, when I click save after I manually add the long and lat, I get:

> TypeError at /admin/users/location/add/ Cannot set Location
>   SpatialProxy (POINT) with value of type:

Comment: what is the full TypeError you are getting? you cut it off right before the important part

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong `Point` class. `Point` should be imported from `django.contrib.gis.geos` not `users.models.Point` if you are using it with a `PointField`

Your imports should be as follows:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
```

Comment: Thanks, I had from django.contrib.gis.db import models, I actually have 2 imports. That and from django.db import models

Comment: I added the above, but unforutanely it doesn't work. If I don't have the save method, I can successfully save the model

Comment: @Roma you should only import models from `django.contrib.gis.db`, not both. Can you edit your answer to include all of your imports?

Comment: Instead of importing both, I now did from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models and from django.db import models . Everything works fine now

Comment: Are you saying that I should remove from django.db import models completely?

Comment: @Roma, yes. The `django.contrib.gis.db.models` is an extension of `django.db.models` that adds more functionality for GeoDjango. You were importing one as `models` then overwriting that declaration with the other import.

Comment: I am getting the error message - AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.gis.db.models' has no attribute 'Pointfield'

Comment: I realised I was writing Pointfield when it should be PointField (capital F).

Answer (score 0):

> Import Model from Given Code

```py
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models
```

> Then Write Your Code

```py
    class Teacher(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
        related_name='Teacher')
        placename = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=255)
        latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, 
        verbose_name='Latitude')
        longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True, 
        verbose_name='Longitude')
        location = models.PointField(blank = True, null=True, srid=4326)
        objects = models.GeoManager()

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.location = Point(self.longitude, self.latitude)
            super(Teacher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" 
            save() method.
```